# Predicate Logic Hilbert Proof

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, formal-proofs

In the Hilbert proof system for predicate logic, prove that the formula:

$\exists x~\big(B(x)\to C(x)\big)\to\big(\forall x~B(x)\to\exists x~C(x)\big)$

I'm awful with Hilbert Proofs and have no idea where to even start with this one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When I read the first few words of the question, I was going to ask which of the many Hilbert proof systems you're asking about.  But then I read the formula you're trying to prove and realized that it's not valid (there are counterexamples with just two elements).

Comment: Put in the question wrong when I typed this up. Fixed it now, the final predicate identifier was suppose to be \exists not \forall. I believe the formula is valid now

Comment: See : Elliott Mendelson, [Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=FS-sCQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), CRC Press (6th ed 2015), page 79.

Comment: I'm confused how the example on page 79 of the book is related to this question? Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: In my copy of the book, at page 79 there is the proof.

Comment: In any case, it would be an improvement for you to supply the source of this exercise.  There are many other ways that you might add context to the Question.  Merely saying you "have no idea where to even start with this one" leaves it to your Readers to guess what background you bring to the problem and what you found especially interesting or difficult about it.